# Search Phone internal and external storage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to develop an app with c# coding, which should search phone internal and external memory for specific file types and list them (ex : *.mp3)

I tried

```
Application.persistentDataPath
```

but it returns only the application datapath.

I need a code in C# equal to

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

The above is available in java script i think.

I need to search from root of every storage available using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What it is, you can only use

     Application.persistentDataPath

and that's it.

Comment: @JoeBlow, but it gives only application data path. I need to search whole phone for specific files types like *.mp3

Comment: right - you can only use Application.persistentDataPath and that's it. WIth both iPhone and Android, you have ***no access*** to anything else.  (If you mean a "rooted" android, I have no idea - sorry.)